# Java OOP: how subclass-object use method from superclass (that method has been Override)

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have this example:

```
public class Inheritance {

    public static class Animal {        
        public void Scream() {
            System.out.println("I'm an animal");
        }       
    }

    public  static class Mammal extends Animal{
        public void Scream(){
            System.out.println("I'm a mammal");
        }       
    }

    public  static class Tiger extends Mammal{
        public void Scream(){
            System.out.println("I'm a tiger");
        }       
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Animal tiger = new Tiger();
        tiger.Scream();
    }

}
```

Of course, I will receive: "I'm a tiger". But, I don't know how to print "I'm a mammal" or "I'm an animal"

@: and please answer for me sub-question: in case `Tiger` class, What is superclass of `Tiger`. `Mammal` or `Animal` ?

Please help me :)

Thanks ::)

Comment: That would be `Mammal`. As for the first question, see @Marcus answer.

Comment: @Truth can you give me a link about your answer for my second question please.(to make it clearer)  because below answers, there is an idea that both `Mammal` and `Animal` is superclass of `Tiger` Thanks :)

Comment: The direct super of the `Tiger` class, would be `Mammal`, and the super of `Mammal` would be `Animal`, which makes `Animal` a grandsuper (or an ancestor) of the `Tiger` class. Which would mean that `super.super.Scream()` in the `Tiger` class would print "I'm an animal".

Comment: Oh. thanks for your graceful help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method overriding, java will always check whose object has been created at run time. If you wanna a print "I'm a mammal":

```
Animal m = new Mammal();
m.Scream();
```

this will print "I'm a mammal".

And if you wanna a print "I'm a animal":

```
Animal a = new Animal();
a.Scream();
```

Comment: No. You can't do like that. Because Mammal is sub-class of Animal

Answer (score 3):

Here is code sample :

```
public class Inheritance {

  public static class Animal {        
      public void Scream() {
          System.out.println("I'm an animal");
      }       
  }

  public  static class Mammal extends Animal{
      public void Scream(){
          super.Scream();
          System.out.println("I'm a mammal");
      }       
  }

  public  static class Tiger extends Mammal{
      public void Scream(){
          super.Scream();
          System.out.println("I'm a tiger");
      }       
  }

  public static void main (String[] args){
      Animal tiger = new Tiger();
      tiger.Scream();
  }

}
```

Comment: Oh. no. it's not my idea. because if you call super in class declare, all-object will do like that. But I just want a specified object.

Comment: Ah ok, then you should re-phrase your question a bit!

Comment: Oh, sorry if my question doesn't clear. because I use subclass-object mean "object that its class is a subclass of others"

Answer (score 0):

Java is not like c++ where this could be possible.

You can call super.scream() in each scream method but it will display both :

"I'm a mammal" and "I'm an animal".

I am not sure why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To print "I'm a mammal" you should make an object of Mammal class.

```
 public static void main (String[] args){ 

    Animal mammal = new Mammal(); 
    mammal.Scream(); 
}
```

To print "I'm an animal" you should make an object of Animal class.

```
 public static void main (String[] args){ 

    Animal animal = new Animal(); 
    animal.Scream(); 
}
```

NOTE: In both of the above cases reference variable remains Animal.

Comment: Oh. But like the way you declare, so a mammal will say "I'm a mammal". Mean it's no magic. But I want o tiger still say: "I'm a mammal". And of course, just tiger I like. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1) As the other guys already said, call `super.Scream()` if you want to call the overridden method from the super class. You would have the following output:

```
I'm an animal
I'm a mammal
I'm a tiger
```

2) Tiger implements Mammal, so Mammal is the superclass of Tiger, and since Animal is the superclass of Mammal, Tiger also implements Animal. In other words: Tiger's superclasses are Tiger and Animal.

```
// all of this is valid:
Tiger tiger = new Tiger();
Mammal mammal = tiger;
Animal animal = tiger;
```

If you call `animal.Scream()` the virtual machine knows that `anmial` is of type Tiger and calls the scream method declared in the Tiger class. See [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).